# How can we download and preview a file using lwc in mobile publisher without storing it into salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobile-publisher

I'm having a blob data as a response from an API, I have implemented preview and download functionality of file using lwc, it is working well on the browser but its not working on the mobile publisher.

Note - we are not storing files in the salesforce.

```
handleGetDocument(event) {

    this.loader = true;

    let xAuthToken = this.authInfo.token.id;
    let filelabel = event.target.innerText;
    let fileName = decodeURIComponent(event.target.dataset.filename);
    let fileHash = decodeURIComponent(event.target.dataset.filehash);
    // console.log(decodeURIComponent(event.target.dataset.filename));

    // console.log("event.target.dataset.id =>", event.target.dataset.id);

    let btn = event.target.dataset.id;

    // console.log("download called");
    if (btn == 'preview') {
        console.log("preview called");
        // if (this.Device == 'Desktop' || this.Browser == 'Safari') {
        if (this.Device != null) {
            console.log('1');
            // this.isShowDocument = true;
            // var data_url = URL.createObjectURL(b64toBlob(response, 'application/pdf'));
            // this.documentationBlob = data_url;
            this.previewURL = `/clientportal/s/preview-document?title=${filelabel}&file=${fileHash}`;
            // this.previewURL = data_url;
            // this.handlePreviewWindow();
            window.open(this.previewURL,  "_blank");
            this.loader = false;
        }else{
            getDocs({ xAuthToken, fileName }).then(response => {
                let a = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(a);

                a.target = "_blank";
                a.href = URL.createObjectURL(b64toBlob(response, 'application/pdf'));;
                a.click();
                // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                a.remove();
                
                this.loader = false;
            })
        }
    // } else {
    } else if (btn == 'download' || this.Device != 'Desktop') {
        getDocs({ xAuthToken, fileName }).then(response => {

            let a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);

            a.target = "_blank";
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(b64toBlob(response, 'application/pdf'));
            a.download = String(fileName);
            a.click();
            // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            a.remove();
            
            this.loader = false;
        })
        
    }
    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) {
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];
        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }
        const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
        return blob;
    }
}

handlePreviewWindow() {
    window.open(this.previewURL,  "_blank");
    // window.location.href = this.previewURL;
    // let a = document.createElement("a");
    // document.body.appendChild(a);

    // a.target = "_blank";
    // a.href = this.previewURL;
    // a.click();
    // // window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    // a.remove();
}
```

Comment: even i'm facing the same issue..
your issue got resolved...!?